# Display only the first instance of JSON Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I tried to ask this question, but made it WAY more convoluted than it needed to be, so I am trying to simplify it.

Sample data set, as follows:
ms9ftwk,ms9ftdate,ms9fthome,ms9fth8pts,ms9fthlopts,ms9ftvs,ms9fta8pts,ms9ftalopts,ms9ftaway,ms9ftloc
1,1/1/2018,P1,0,0,vs,0,0,P6,Loc1
1,1/1/2018,P2,0,0,vs,0,0,P5,Loc2
1,1/1/2018,P3,0,0,vs,0,0,P4,Loc3
2,1/2/2018,P4,0,0,vs,0,0,P1,Loc3
2,1/2/2018,P5,0,0,vs,0,0,P2,Loc2
2,1/2/2018,P6,0,0,vs,0,0,P3,Loc1

I am trying to build a Bootstrap 4 card with a heading that shows the Week # - Date in the title (the h4 line in the code below). I am getting 3 instances of Week 1 - 1/1/2018, instead of just one.

```js
//Build the Table Body for Schedule/Weekly Scores
var weeklytbb = '';
var entryweeklytbb = data.feed.entry;
for (var wk1 = 1; wk1 <= 18; wk1++) {
 weeklytbb += '<div class="card border border-dark mb-3">';
 for (var wtbb02 = wk1; wtbb02 < entryweeklytbb.length; wtbb02++) {
  if( entryweeklytbb[wtbb02].gsx$ms9ftwk.$t == wk1 && entryweeklytbb[wtbb02].gsx$ms9ftdate.$t !== '') {
   weeklytbb += '<h4 class="card-header bg-dark text-light text-center">Week ' + wk1 + ' - ' + entryweeklytbb[wtbb02].gsx$ms9ftdate.$t + '</h4>';
  }
 }
 weeklytbb += '<div class="card-body p-0">';
 weeklytbb += 'My Data Goes Here - This Already Works As Intended and is Irrelevant';
 weeklytbb += '</div></div>';
}
```

Comment: You should create groups based on weeks number and then create cards for each group

Comment: in your error message, it is clearly mention data is not defined. can you provide us your data?

Comment: I provided a sample set of data in the main post?

If you'd like to see the live data, it is here: https://www.westmibcapl.com/leagues/ (You will need to expand Monday on the left, and choose "Monday GR Singles" and then click on "Weekly Schedule and Scores" to display the actual live data and what is happening when that javascript fires).

Comment: I found way to work around by adding a column to my data (ms9ftwkmst) and only putting a value in the first row of each instance and filtering my query based on that.